# An error occurred (InternalFailure) when calling the InvokeEndpoint operation: An exception occurred while sending request to model

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, machine-learning, xgboost, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to host an XGBoost model that I have trained locally on an AWS Sagemaker Endpoint but I am receiving the following error when invoking the endpoint:

> An error occurred (InternalFailure) when calling the InvokeEndpoint operation (reached max retries: 4): An exception occurred while sending request to model. Please contact customer support regarding request.

The model works as expected locally and I save it using the following before uploading to S3:

```
model.fit(args)
model.save_model(model_save_loc)
model_tar_loc = model_save_loc + '.tar.gz'
!tar czvf $model_tar_loc $model_save_loc
```

I am hosting the model through the MultiDataModel function,

```
container = retrieve("xgboost", region, "1.3-1")
mme = MultiDataModel(
    name=model_name,
    role=role,
    model_data_prefix=model_data_prefix,
    image_uri=container,
    sagemaker_session=sagemaker_session,
)

predictor = mme.deploy(
    initial_instance_count=1, instance_type=instance_type, endpoint_name=model_name,     
)
```

The MultiDataModel deploy works as expected with no errors, and if I do:

```
list(mme.list_models())
```

It returns the expected list of models:

```
model_1.tar.gz
model_2.tar.gz
etc..
```

I invoke the model using the following:

```
runtime_client = boto3.client("runtime.sagemaker")

response = runtime_client.invoke_endpoint(
    EndpointName="model_name", ContentType="text/csv", Body=payload, TargetModel='model_1.tar.gz'
)
result = response["Body"].read().decode("ascii")
```

I have experimented with various ways of creating the payload but none change the error message.

The local XGBoost model was trained using XGBoost version 1.3.1 (same as the Docker version).

CloudWatch provides only the following:

> 2021-06-26 10:48:36,865 [INFO ] pool-1-thread-1 ACCESS_LOG - /10.32.0.2:37106 "GET /ping HTTP/1.1" 200 0

There is no way of contacting customer support through the basic plan, as advised by the error.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by trying to host each endpoint individually instead of using MultiDataModel, which provided more detail Log Errors in CloudWatch.

For me, the error was that my models were saved as:

model-1.tar.gz -> models/model-1

By default, the XGBoost container will search "model-1-tar.gz" folder for files (after unzipping), whilst my model was found within a subfolder. Moving this up a level solved the issue.